# function is not working inside document.onkeydown

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a function :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        function Next() {
            alert("IM GOING TO DO SOMETHING NOW");
        }
        document.onkeydown = function (e) 
        {
           if (!e) e = window.event;
           switch (e.keyCode) 
           {
            case 37:
                //alert("Left arrow");
                Next();
                break;
            } //End OnKeyDown

        }); //End Document load
```

In console says "Next() is not a function"

What am I doing wrong ?

UPDATE :
OK i think since i was using jquery .next() and .prev() in other parts of the code it was not working i just changed the next() to go_next() and it works just fine

thanks

Comment: You are missing a closing `}`, the correct indention makes it more apparent. However, if that was the problem, you would not even get any message in the console. Please provide more information about your problem and a correct example.

Comment: You should not just accept an answer for the sake of accepting it. If your problem was actually different, please update you question with the necessary information and write your own answer to it. This will be more helpful to others. Right now, the accepted answer doesn't make sense given the error message you posted, and the error message doesn't make sense given the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot closing braces on your switch statement ([JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7hsc4/)):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
function Next() 
{
    alert("IM GOING TO DO SOMETHING NOW");
} 
    document.onkeydown=function(e){

        if (!e) e=window.event;
       switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
             //alert("Left arrow");
            Next();
            break;
       }
} //End OnKeyDown

}); //End Document load
```

Comment: If that was the problem, the OP would see a different error message. The code wouldn't run because of the syntax error.

Comment: I've copied and pasted OP's code into JSfiddle, saw a syntax error, added the '}' and now it's working.

Comment: Yes. But the OP gets the error message  "Next() is not a function". Hence we can assume that the code is syntactically correct and that the problem is something else.

Comment: yeah this is not my real code the real code contains 500 lines and it realy confiusing (im not a pro Coder :/ ) but i think defining a function in document.ready should work fine right ?

Comment: Yes, defining functions within functions works fine, but they will be only accessible from the scope that they are defined in.

Comment: @Damen: Since your example works fine with the syntax error fixed, the problem must be somewhere else. You reduced the problem too much. We cannot help you if we cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: in my real code i dont get expected error it shows me Next() is not a function im using firebug's console

Comment: Then please try again at reducing the real code so we can help you with the actual problem :)